# Unable to update my contact records

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written a trigger to update the contact's individual balance field depending on the number of contacts associated with the account but I am unable to view it on the UI

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact(before insert, before update, after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete){
SWITCH ON Trigger.operationType{
    WHEN BEFORE_UPDATE{
        AmountSplitTriggerHandler.AmountSplitAfterUpdate(Trigger.new);
    }
}



 public class AmountSplitTriggerHandler {
    public static void AmountSplitAfterUpdate(List<Contact> listOfInsertedContacts){
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Contact conObj : listOfInsertedContacts){
            if(conObj.AccountId != NULL)
            accountIds.add(conObj.AccountId);
        }
        List<Account> listOfAccountsWithContacts = [SELECT Id, Name, Balance__c, 
                                                   (SELECT Id, Name, Individual_Balance__c 
                                                    FROM Contacts) 
                                                    FROM Account
                                                    WHERE Balance__c > 0];
        
        List<Contact> listOfContactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
        
        for(Account accObj : listOfAccountsWithContacts){
            if(!listOfAccountsWithContacts.isEmpty()){
                Decimal totalContactsPerAccount = accObj.contacts.size();
                Decimal totalAmountPerContact = accObj.Balance__c/totalContactsPerAccount;
                System.debug('Total Contacts Per Account: '+ totalContactsPerAccount);
                System.debug('totalAmountPerContact: '+ totalAmountPerContact);
                for(Contact con : accObj.contacts){
                         con.Individual_Balance__c =  totalAmountPerContact;
                    System.debug('con.Individual_Balance__c'+ con.Individual_Balance__c );
                    System.debug('totalAmountPerContact: '+totalAmountPerContact);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only avoid performing DML when you are:

- In a before insert/update trigger
- Make your change on a record instance contained in `trigger.new` or `trigger.newMap`

You're not satisfying that second condition. If you want to avoid DML, then you need to operate on the records in `listOfInsertedContacts`.

The issue you'll run into with that, though, is that you'd only update the triggered contacts. Since you're dividing the Account amount among all of its related contacts, that's insufficient. You need to work on all of the related contacts, which means that *DML is required here*.

#### DML is required... or is it?

An alternative approach you could take would be to store the number of Contacts related to an Account *on that Account*. You could then have a formula field on Contact to perform the division.

`Account__r.Balance__c/Account__r.Contact_Count__c`

You'd obviously need to handle the situation when a Contact has no Account or somehow the Account has 0 in its contract count, but that's a simple check. You'd still need a trigger on Contact to update the Contract Count on the Account (since we can't make a Rollup Summary Field of Contact on Account).

#### Moving forward

- Your query currently doesn't filter based on the Account Ids that you've gathered. You should fix that.
- `listOfAccountsWithContacts` will never be empty inside your for loop (because you're looping over `listOfAccountsWithContacts`), so that check should be removed
- Calling `accObj.contacts.size()` will fail if an Account has enough (~200 or more) Contacts. The safe approach here would be to have two loops over `accObj.contacts`. The first to increment a counter so you get the number of Contacts, and the second to set the new Individual_Balance__c (which you're already doing)
- You need to add the Contacts to your `listOfContactsToUpdate`
- You need to `update listOfContactsToUpdate;`, and do so in a way that prevents recursion

For handling the recursion, the simplest mechanism that works (without issues like causing you to only process the first 200 records) is having a static boolean variable in an Apex class, setting it before performing your DML, and then unsetting it after the DML finishes.

e.g.

```java
Utility.preventContactTrigger = true;
update myContacts;
Utility.preventContactTrigger = false;
```

You'd also need to set your trigger (or your individual handler classes) up to honor that flag. e.g.

```java
public static void AmountSplitAfterUpdate(List<Contact> listOfInsertedContacts){
    // Skip running the rest of this method (by returning early)if we 
    //   got here because of the update 
    if(Utility.preventContactTrigger){ return; }

    // If we get to this line, then we can just do things as normal
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    // ... and so on
```

The static boolean variable needs to be defined in an Apex class because static variables defined in triggers are completely useless. It's syntactically valid to declare a static variable in a trigger, but the static variable is reset between each context (before update -> after update) and between each chunk of 200 records. A static variable that doesn't retain its value for the entire transaction defeats the purpose of having it be declared as static.